# Magento 2 How to add rich snippets code on products using Schema.org tags?

Tags: magento2, google-analytics

I am looking to add Google snippets schema organization code on product page in Magento 2.2.I have searched on forums but didn't get any exact answer.
I have implemented in Magento1 but not idea how to do same in Magento 2.

Please help me if anyone have any idea and implemented before.

Thanks,

Comment: Create a custom module and insert the rich snippets element based on the product data. Or buy an existing module to do it for you such as https://amasty.com/google-rich-snippets-for-magento-2.html (I didnt test it)